# Add authentication for certain pages of Jekyll site

Tags: authentication, jekyll

I have a certain page my Jekyll site that I only want to make available to people from my organization's domain (call it example.com).

Am I correct in my understanding that it's not possible to restrict access to certain pages because — as is the nature of a static site  — everything has already been served at once?

I'm aware of the `jekyll-auth` plugin to authenticate users against GitHub, but my situation would require that authentication through Google sign-in.

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/apcj/jekyll-google-auth

Comment: https://blog.termian.dev/posts/static-site-auth/

Answer (score 8):

Jekyll is just a static site generator, so anything related to authentication will depend on what you have available on the webserver that is hosting the site.

Take a look at the [Jekyll Google Auth](https://github.com/apcj/jekyll-google-auth) plugin for example:
https://github.com/apcj/jekyll-google-auth

It's basically a trick... Anytime a request comes in for a page, they run it through [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) (using the _site folder as the static file folder, just as public would be normally), and authenticate it using [apcj/sinatra-google-auth](https://github.com/apcj/sinatra-google-auth).

So in this case, you know that your webserver must have [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) for this authentication method to work.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative would be to password protect your Jekyll site with HTTP basic auth. Aerobatic provides such a feature for static sites hosted with Bitbucket. And yes, you can protect only certain directories of the site.

https://www.aerobatic.com/blog/password-protect-a-jekyll-site

Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of Aerobatic

Comment: Are you still using http basic auth? Ussually you get that little popup with user and pasword. But I'm seeing a web based login when I go here --> https://dashboard.aerobatic.com/login

Comment: This link appears to be offline

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Netlify](https://netlify.com) to add authentication to any static site not just jekyll. Deploy your site for free on netlify and use their [identity widget.](https://docs.netlify.com/visitor-access/identity/).